# com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'lastchange' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, datetime

I have a small problem. I'm trying to write a small Spring Boot Application and use Hibernate. This works as well as well, unfortunately I get the above mentioned error message when building `<mvn clean package>`. The error does not occur until the tests are started. Actually, it's also logical, Hibernate or JUnit tries to use `0000-00-00 00:00:00` as the test date. MySQL does not allow that. how can i tell the test to say `Now ()?

The Testclass:

```
    package com.webservice.spring;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ApiApplicationTests 
{

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() 
    {

    }

}
```

this is the definition in the model:

```
@NotNull
@Generated(value=GenerationTime.ALWAYS) 
@Column(name = "lastchange", columnDefinition = "DATETIME", nullable = false)
private LocalDate lastchanged;
```

and a snippet of the StackTrace:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'lastchange' at row 1
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3971)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2483)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1552)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2607)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1480)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:431)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:449)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.migrateTable(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:253)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:170)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:60)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:134)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
```

what can i do to prevent the test from failing?

Comment: `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Australia/Broken_Hill"))`? You may substitute your favourite time zone.

Comment: in the testclass ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do either of the following

- Changing the default value for a column with an ALTER TABLE
  statement, e.g.

> ALTER TABLE users MODIFY created datetime  NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01'

- Change the date column to allow NULL values, and update the existing
  rows to change the zero dates to null values

Comment: The field is filled by MySQL itself.
it has by default: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 0):

The Answer:

in the Model Class:

```
@Column(name = "lastchange", columnDefinition = "DATETIME default '1900-01-01 00:00:00'", nullable = false)
private LocalDate lastchanged;
```

you can set the default in the Column Anotation